# js скрипт после динамического появления элементов

Tags: javascript, html

Есть js(jquery) скрипт с функцией-событием на нажатие элементов с id='foo'! Скрипт прекрасно срабатывает,если кнопка с id='foo' прописана в html.Но
если нам нужно в ходе работы добавлять динамически элементы путем jquery.append с тем же id='foo', то скрипт на их нажатие не сработает, только на статически прописанный в html.Как быть?Что сделать,чтобы js мог срабатывать на вновь появившиеся элементы?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) { 
  $( "#slim" ).click(function(event) { 
    alert('test ok'); 
  }); 
  $( "#slimgen" ).click(function(event) { 
     $("#boo").append('<input type="button" value="slim" id="slim"/>'); 
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="generate" id="slimgen"/> 
<div id="boo"> 
  <input type="button" value="slim" id="slim"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: как вариант - переписать функцию чтоб вызывалась по `onclick` текущему эл-ту

Comment: не помогает,пробовали

Comment: Значит не верно пробовали, киньте реализацию

Comment: <script>

$(document).ready(function($) {

  $( "#slim" ).click(function(event) {

  alert('test ok');
  });


  $( "#slimgen" ).click(function(event) {

  $("#boo").append('<input type="button" value="slim" id="slim"/>');
  });



  });





</script>


<input type="button" value="generate" id="slimgen"/>
<div id="boo">
<input type="button" value="slim" id="slim"/>
</div>

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.another-class', function() {` - всегда спасает. Если у вас есть элемент `#slim`, то зачем вы такой же добавляете?

Comment: для примера полегче, а вообще, будет привязываться к кнопкам добавить в корзину, естественно надо будет разные id делать

Comment: Класс один и тот же делайте, а различать по `data-id`

Comment: Спасибо большое, а эта фича только по классам? или по id тоже можно?$(document).on('click', '.another-class', function() {

Comment: @user321474 Хоть id, хоть любой другой селектор, который работает в CSS. Можно даже `$(document).on('click', '#id.class ~ .bubu', function() {`

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения клиентской оптимизации на слушатель не стоит вешать весь документ. При клике на элемент, будет считываться весь dom.

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
  // так делать не стоит $( document ).on... 

  // Правильно делать слушатель родительскому элементу, а не всему документу.
  $( "#slimgen" ).on("click", ".slim", function(event) { 
    alert('test ok'); 
  }); 
});
```

Если в дом много элементов, а слушатель **$( document ).on** не один, то произойдёт очень заметное снижение производительности. Особенно это будет заметно на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: Добавил таймер, раз в минуту появляется элемент и что тогда ? ... Раз говорим про оптимизацию, так на родителя вешать будет лучше ! Чем например на 10 000 строк таблицы ...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="generate" id="slimgen" onclick="add($(this))"/> 
<div id="boo"> 
  <input type="button" value="slim" id="slim" onclick="sayOk();"/> 
</div>

<script>
function sayOk(){
 alert('test OK');
}

function add(e){
 let elem = e.next('div#boo').find('#slim');
  let clone_elem = elem.clone();
  $('#boo').append(clone_elem);
}
</script>
```

Ну а так-то, `id` должен быть только 1 на странице, с дублированием эл-тов дублируется и он, так что придумайте что-то другое вместо него (и тогда может нужно будет функции подправить в соответствии с новыми "именами").